# sum of last 6 rows for same day of week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help to write the sql code to sum last 6 weeks for same day of the week and predict the number for next day of week.

please find the below data

```
create table #t (dy varchar(10), dt datetime, code varchar(4), wd varchar(10), num int)
insert into #t values
('Wednesday', '2023-03-01','c','101A',5),
('Wednesday', '2023-03-08','c','101A',3),
('Wednesday', '2023-03-15','c','101A',1),
('Wednesday', '2023-03-22','c','101A',1),
('Wednesday', '2023-03-29','c','101A',3),
('Wednesday', '2023-04-05','c','101A',2),
('Wednesday', '2023-04-12','c','101A',5),
('Wednesday', '2023-04-19','c','101A',2),
('Wednesday', '2023-04-26','c','101A',0),
('Wednesday', '2023-05-03','c','101A',6),
('Wednesday', '2023-05-10','c','101A',4),
('Wednesday', '2023-05-17','c','101A',3),
('Wednesday', '2023-05-24','c','101A',5),
('Wednesday', '2023-05-31','c','101A',1),
('Wednesday', '2023-05-07','c','101A',0),

('Wednesday', '2023-03-01','c','102A',4),
('Wednesday', '2023-03-08','c','102A',6),
('Wednesday', '2023-03-15','c','102A',4),
('Wednesday', '2023-03-22','c','102A',3),
('Wednesday', '2023-03-29','c','102A',6),
('Wednesday', '2023-04-05','c','102A',2),
('Wednesday', '2023-04-12','c','102A',1),
('Wednesday', '2023-04-19','c','102A',2),
('Wednesday', '2023-04-26','c','102A',3),
('Wednesday', '2023-05-03','c','102A',2),
('Wednesday', '2023-05-10','c','102A',5),
('Wednesday', '2023-05-17','c','102A',0),
('Wednesday', '2023-05-24','c','102A',1),
('Wednesday', '2023-05-31','c','102A',1),
('Wednesday', '2023-06-07','c','102A',0),

('Tuesday', '2023-02-28','d','101A',2),
('Tuesday', '2023-03-07','d','101A',3),
('Tuesday', '2023-03-14','d','101A',8),
('Tuesday', '2023-03-21','d','101A',10),
('Tuesday', '2023-03-28','d','101A',3),
('Tuesday', '2023-04-04','d','101A',2),
('Tuesday', '2023-04-11','d','101A',5),
('Tuesday', '2023-04-18','d','101A',2),
('Tuesday', '2023-04-25','d','101A',4),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-02','d','101A',6),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-09','d','101A',3),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-16','d','101A',4),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-23','d','101A',5),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-30','d','101A',1),
('Tuesday', '2023-06-06','d','101A',6),

('Tuesday', '2023-02-28','cd','103',5),
('Tuesday', '2023-03-07','cd','103',5),
('Tuesday', '2023-03-14','cd','103',4),
('Tuesday', '2023-03-21','cd','103',1),
('Tuesday', '2023-03-28','cd','103',3),
('Tuesday', '2023-04-04','cd','103',2),
('Tuesday', '2023-04-11','cd','103',4),
('Tuesday', '2023-04-18','cd','103',2),
('Tuesday', '2023-04-25','cd','103',0),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-02','cd','103',3),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-09','cd','103',2),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-16','cd','103',1),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-23','cd','103',5),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-30','cd','103',1),
('Tuesday', '2023-06-06','cd','103',0)
```

for ex:- sum of num of last 6 (2023-06-06,2023-05-30,2023-05-23,2023-05-16,2023-05-09,2023-05-02) rows for 2023-06-13

```
select * From #t

create table #t_result (dy varchar(10), dt datetime, code varchar(4), wd varchar(10), num int)

insert into #t_result values
('Tuesday', '2023-06-13','cd','103',12),
('Tuesday', '2023-06-06','cd','103',12),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-30','cd','103',13),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-23','cd','103',12),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-16','cd','103',13),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-09','cd','103',14),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-02','cd','103',12),

('Tuesday', '2023-06-13','d','101A',25),
('Tuesday', '2023-06-06','d','101A',23),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-30','d','101A',24),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-23','d','101A',24),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-16','d','101A',22),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-09','d','101A',22),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-02','d','101A',26)
```

Comment: So what help do you need? What is the difficulty *you* are having solving the problem? What are you expected results? What was your attempt? Why didn't it work? ["Can someone help me?" isn't an actual question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983)

Comment: Hi thanks for looking into this.. i tried using window function but could get the desired result which needed is in the table #t_result      SELECT
    dy, a_pre, [sum],wd, code
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            dy,wd, code
        ,   FIRST_VALUE( dt ) OVER (ORDER BY dt ROWS 6 PRECEDING) AS a_pre
        ,   SUM( num ) OVER (ORDER BY dt, code,wd ROWS 6 PRECEDING) AS [sum]
        ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt) AS rownum
        FROM
            #t
    ) AS data
WHERE wd='101A' and
    rownum % 6 = 0

Comment: [Edit] your question, don't put your attempt(s) in the comments. Make sure you address the rest of the comment too.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any input/expected output but I am assuming that in your query you need to join the table t with itself based on the day of the week (dy column) and the code (code column) and calculate the sum of num for the rows within the last 6 weeks using `DATEADD(WEEK, -6, t2.dt)` and t1.dt <= t2.dt to make sure that the sum includes the current row as well :

```
    create table t (dy varchar(10), dt datetime, code varchar(4), wd varchar(10), num int)
    insert into t values
    ('Tuesday', '2023-06-13','cd','103',12),
('Tuesday', '2023-06-06','cd','103',12),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-30','cd','103',13),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-23','cd','103',12),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-16','cd','103',13),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-09','cd','103',14),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-02','cd','103',12),

('Tuesday', '2023-06-13','d','101A',25),
('Tuesday', '2023-06-06','d','101A',23),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-30','d','101A',24),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-23','d','101A',24),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-16','d','101A',22),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-09','d','101A',22),
('Tuesday', '2023-05-02','d','101A',26)
```

```
14 rows affected
```

```
SELECT t1.dy, t1.code, SUM(t2.num) AS total_num
FROM t AS t1
LEFT JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.dy = t2.dy
    AND t1.code = t2.code
    AND t1.dt >= DATEADD(WEEK, -6, t2.dt)
    AND t1.dt <= t2.dt


GROUP BY t1.dy, t1.code
ORDER BY t1.dy, t1.code
```

| dy | code | total_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tuesday | cd | 348 |
| Tuesday | d | 665 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-0BSkFNO)